# What can I do, to prevent a component, when I hover, the result is false?

Tags: hover

Do you know how to fix this problem? I have a useState that marks true if you hover and false if you release the hover. You hover over a map of cards, and normally it goes true if you hover, but if you do it very quickly, there is always one card that when I hover it goes false

Prevent a card from being false when I hover in a react component